# How can I change the default pager for Python's help() debugger command?

Tags: python, linux, command-line, configuration, pager

I'm currently doing some work in a server (Ubuntu) without admin rights nor contact with the administrator. When using the `help(command)` in the python command line I get an error.

Here's an example:

```
>>> help(someCommand) 
/bin/sh: most: command not found
```

So, this error indicates that most pager is not currently installed. However, the server I'm working on has "more" and "less" pagers installed. So, how can I change the default pager configuration for this python utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is annoyingly difficult to research, but I think I found it.

The built-in `help` generates its messages using the standard library `pydoc` module (the module is also intended to be usable as a standalone script). In [that](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html) documentation, we find:

> When printing output to the console, **pydoc** attempts to paginate the output for easier reading. If the `PAGER` environment variable is set, **pydoc** will use its value as a pagination program.

So, presumably, that's been set to `most` on your system. Assuming it won't break anything else on your system, just unset or change it. (It still pages without a value set - even on Windows. I assume it has a built-in fallback.)

Comment: I wouldn't expect any problems to arise by just setting it in the environment (`$> export PAGER=less`), but if by chance it were a problem you could just `$>PAGER=less python` each time (or make an alias for that).

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Dave s solution + the documentation location solved the problem. Nothing's broken :)

Comment: I now use Linux, and was able to test this: using `PAGER=cat python` results in `help` printing the output without paging, such that it remains in the scroll buffer. It pages on my system by default, even with `PAGER` unset; I don't know what the default logic is.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom `most` script that just invokes `less` (or even `more`).

The steps would be:

1. Set up a script called `most`, the contents of which are:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    less ${@:1}  # wierdess is just "all arguments except argument 0"
```

2. Put that script in a location that is on your `PATH`

Then `most filename` should just run `less` on that file, and that command should get called from in your python interpreter.

To be honest though, I'd just use Karl's approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the various pager options in [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/pydoc.py#L1556). That function can be replaced to return whatever is desired. For example:

```py
import pydoc

pydoc.getpager = lambda: lambda text: pydoc.pipepager(text, 'less')
```